# How do I create a divisibility criterion?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Is there a pattern?

I have no idea how to create, just the operation of some divisibility criteria ...

How difficult is it to create an even and odd number criterion if you have one? Is there a greater difficulty if you are cousin or not?

For example: how to create a divisibility criterion for $251$ (prime number) and $342$

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Please give some concrete examples.

Comment: What do you call 'a cousin'? A prime number? (Please edit both references to 'cousin'.)

Comment: Yes! Prime number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the method in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69772/242)

$\!\!\bmod 251\!:\ {-}25(10)\equiv 1\ $ so $\,10^{-1}\equiv -25$

hence $\, 10b+a\equiv 0\! \overset{\times 10^{\large -1\!\!\!}}\iff b-25a\equiv 0,\ $ i.e. $\,\bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{251\mid 10b+a\iff 251\mid b-25a}$

e.g. $\ 251\mid 753\iff 251\mid 75-25(3) = 0$

Similarly $\ 171\mid 10b+a\iff 171\mid b-17a\,$ which - with an even test - yields your $342$ test.

Comment: $171=9\cdot 19$ so we only need divisibility by $19$. ($19|10b+a\Leftrightarrow 19|b+2a$ etc.)

Comment: @Stinking Yes, in many special cases there are various optimizations available, but above I was aiming only to show how that general method works uniformly for divisors $\equiv 1\pmod{\!10}\ \ $